# hidden google map not loading in fancybox on opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, fancybox

I am having a really tough time working out how to to view my google map when clicking a link to open it

currently when clicking an link I get this result

[image]

as you can see the map only loads a tiny bit in the corner

This is the html

```
<a href="#map-canvas" id="inline" class="fancybox" id="inline">
            <img id="map-image" alt="Tea Map" src="wp-content/themes/Tea-interactive/assets/images/map.png" />
        </a>
```

and here is my fancybox code

```
    $("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'afterShow': function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is *normal* behavior for the google maps api if you create it in a hidden object.

The element it is created in will need to have a size (height/width) so the map can be drawn correctly.

What you need to do is create the map **after** its container element is **visible** or **has a size**. (hint: css `visibility` attribute)

Answer (score 5):

In your fancybox you have to initialize the google maps after showing like:

```
    $("a#inline").fancybox({
        'hideOnContentClick': false,
        'afterShow': function(){
             initialize(map);
      }
    });

function initialize(map){
   //your code to initialize the google map example: (ZOOM_LEVEL AND DISABLE_DEFAULT should be set above)
   var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 30),
      zoom: ZOOM_LEVEL,
      disableDefaultUI: DISABLE_DEFAULT,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id),
    mapOptions);
}
```